# Robot Framework robotframework-selenium2library 1.8.0

Tags: robotframework

For some reason my script is failing halfway due to element not found..however if I add ***sleep  2*** under each command the script passed. Any ideas? I tried xpath,css, & Sizzle.

Error ***Element locator 'excel-link' did not match any elements.***

If happens with all browsers (Chrome,FF, & Safari), any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code with us. Did you try to use `Wait Until ...` keywords from Selenium2Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you're trying to access elements on the page before the page has finished rendering. This is a very common mistake when writing automated tests of web pages.

The most common solution is to wait for the element to be available before you try to use it. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
example
    wait for page to contain element    excel-link
    click link  excel-link
```